# TTreeView Code conversion

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

I would like to know how to implement the following code that I was using in Delphi 6 in Delphi XE6 using FireMonkey.

```
Node1:=Quick_Calc.EquivalenciesTree.Items.Add(nil,Text);

Node1:=Quick_Calc.EquivalenciesTree.Items.Add(Node1,Text);

Node1:=Quick_Calc.lEquivalenciesTree.Items.AddChild(Node1,Text);
```

Comment: I appreciate your prompt answer. I notice that you create your own AddChild Function.

Answer (score 2):

A quick test shows that this code works, with a new FMX HD Desktop app with an empty TTreeView on the form:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Root: TTreeViewItem;
  Item: TTreeViewItem;
  SubItem: TTreeViewItem;
  i, j: Integer;

  function AddChild(Node: TTreeViewItem; NodeText: string): TTreeViewItem;
  begin
    Result := TTreeViewItem.Create(Self);
    Result.Text := NodeText;
    if Node <> nil then
      Result.Parent := Node
    else
      Result.Parent := TreeView1;
  end;

begin
  Root := TTreeViewItem.Create(Self);
  Root.Text := 'Root node';
  Root.Parent := TreeView1;
  for i := 1 to 10 do
  begin
    Item := AddChild(Root, Format('Item %d', [i]));
    for j := 1 to 2 do
      SubItem := AddChild(Item, Format('Child %d of Item %d', [j, i]));
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Procedure Carga_Nodo;
Begin
 If NivAct=0 Then
  Begin
{
   Nodo1:=Quick_Calc.ArbolEquivalencias.Items.Add(nil,CadMem)
}
   Nodo[I].Text:=CadMem;
   Nodo[I].Parent:=Form1.ArbolEquivalencias;
   NivAnt:=NivAct;
   IndPad:=I;
   IndHer:=I;
   IndHij:=I;
  End
 Else
  Begin
  If NivAnt=NivAct Then
   Begin
{   Nodo1:=Quick_Calc.ArbolEquivalencias.Items.Add(Nodo1,CadMem)}
    Nodo[I].Text:=CadMem;
    Nodo[I].Parent:=Nodo[IndPad];
   End
  Else
   If NivAct>NivAnt Then
    Begin
{    Nodo1:=Quick_Calc.ArbolEquivalencias.Items.AddChild(Nodo1,CadMem)}
    IndPad:=I-1;
    Nodo[I].Text:=CadMem;
    Nodo[I].Parent:=Nodo[IndPad];
    End
   Else
    Begin
     J:=I;
     Repeat
{      NodoPadre:=NodoPadre.GetPrev;}
      NodoPadre:=GetPrevItem(Nodo[J]);
      NivAnt:=Nodo[J].Level;
      J:=J-1;
     Until NivAnt=NivAct;
     J:=J+1;
{     Nodo1:=Quick_Calc.ArbolEquivalencias.Items.Add(Nodo1,CadMem)}
     IndHer:=J;
     Nodo[I].Text:=CadMem;
     Nodo[I].Parent:=Nodo[IndHer];
    End;
   NivAnt:=NivAct;
  End;
End;
```

Comment: Ugh. Where are all those variables coming from? Even I and J aren't local. And I fail to see what that code has to do with your original questions. Stick with Ken's code.